# Scraping beginner with jsoup in Android

Tags: android, web-scraping, jsoup

I am newbie and trying to scrap some website in Android with Jsoup. The structure of HTML elements looks like this:

```
<div id="latest-article">
    <article>
         <div class="post-text">
              <h3 class="title">
                  <a href="links">article_title</a>
              </h3>
         </div>
    </article>
    <article>
    ...
    </article>
    <article>
    ...
    </article>
</div>
```

I wanna get `article-title` and `links` to make an ArrayAdapter for my articles ListView.

```
   doc = Jsoup.connect("http://muslim.or.id").get();

   // get all articles
   Elements articles = doc.select("div#latest-article");
   for (Element article : articles) {
      ...
   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my little effort:

```
Element latestArticle = doc.select("div#latest-article").first();
Elements articles = latestArticle.select("article");
for (Element article : articles) {
    // get the value from href attribute
    Element link = article.select("div.post-text > h3.title > a").first();
    String linkHref = link.attr("href");
    String linkText = link.text();

    System.out.println(linkText + " - " + linkHref);
}
```